# All drivers accidentally removed, how can i reinstall them (ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS)

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-drivers

In order to get a touchpad driver(for dell Vostro-3568) I just copy-pasted code in the terminal(`xserver...-xorg-core`) and now almost all drivers are removed. The keyboard does not work so I cannot login to my account and even in guest, cant do anything in terminal. Only thing I can use as input is the touchpad on which I can only use left click (due to its design and for which I tried to install a driver). Is there any direct executable package for drivers(at least keyboard) or any method to reinstall Ubuntu without losing previous data?

Comment: Use a live session or grub-rescue.

Answer (score 0):

You could boot your computer with a live-medium (it doesn't even have to be ubuntu's), you'd be able to use your keyboard and etc. You'd also be able to save your personal data, if you're planning to reinstall Ubuntu. Though I'd suggest you to try the recovery mode first. Just hold down the left shift key (sometimes it is Esc) when booting and choose recovery mode.

Comment: I tried reinstalling drivers using chroot on live usb and also in recovery mode but none of them helped. But I was able to save my previous data using the live medium.